# React event is undefined when checkbox selected

Tags: reactjs, contentful

I have multiple checkboxes, when i clicked on them i want to display items which includes selected tags.

my code is below. it works fine when i console.log(response.items). but when i add
    `this.setState({ itemsByTag: response.items })` i got an `event is undefined` error after i click on checkbox

```
 componentDidUpdate(){
   this.onBoxChange()
 }

 onBoxChange = (event) => {
   console.log(event.target.checked, event.target.name)
   this.getItemsByTag(event.target.name)
 }

 getItemsByTag = (tagname) => {
   this.client
     .getEntries({
       content_type: "models",
       "fields.tags[all]": tagname
     })
     .then(response => this.setState({ itemsByTag: response.items }))
     .catch(console.error)
 }
```

Comment: You did not bind your handler to any event. Instead you are calling it yourself in `componentDidUpdate` and without providing any argument, so of course `event` is `undefined`.

Comment: because you are calling `onBoxChange` from `componentDidUpdate` method without event object, and `didUpdate` will get called if you do setState. thats why getting this error "event is undefined"

Comment: I see, thanks for the quick responses